# How to make NDEF text record human unreadable?

Tags: java, android, nfc, ndef

I have a nfc tag with ndef text record. The text is

```
Paris/London
```

and anyone with nfc tag reading app can read it like this.

How should i encrypt/encode this text so that is human unreadable? I want my app to decrypt/decode it so it can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using these Strings, you could set up a table where you map the possible Strings to integers. For example: Paris -> 0, London -> 1, etc. Your tag could then contain the text "0/1", which cannot be interpreted by anyone who does not have your table.

Another possibility would be to simply encrypt the String. However, to store it then on an NFC tag you would either have to create your own NDEF record type or, for example, use Base64 encoding to be able to store the encrypted string in an NDEF Text record (as it is only supposed to contain human-readable text).

Comment: I will very likely also have coordinates (lat,lng) in this strings. So i will probably use base64. If someone finds out that this is base 64 encdoed, can't he just encode it and see the text?

Comment: Yes, Base64 encoding is only applied in case you want to store arbitrary binary data in a place where only readable ASCII can be stored. For keeping data secret, you should use encryption.